# C++ - stop an infinite loop - tracing a contour

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have been trying to trace the contour (line) of a surface in an 2D grayscale image using OpenCV and C++, but, I keep running into an infinite loop. I've tried all sorts of debugging, and cannot rectify my problem. Please help!

My image looks like this: http://snag.gy/fAs9a.jpg  (fourth image)

This is what my "initial" contour looks like: http://snag.gy/fAs9a.jpg  (fifth image)

This is what I have done so far:

1. Initialize a mask of the image which contains an "initial" contour of the surface in the image.
2. In the mask, get all those point coordinates whose values are greater than 255, and store them in a vector.
3. For each coordinate-set, increment the row value to go down the current column in the image, and find the first pixel which has all its neighbors that are greater than a threshold.
4. Once the pixel is found, go to the next column and repeat the process until all pixels are found in all columns.
5. If no such pixel is found, then set last (column,row) value to 0.
6. Once all bright pixels are found, this constitutes a "final contour"

**Problem:** I keep running into an infinite loop even though my logic seems sound and my code also looks reasonable. There might not be a pixel found in the current column that has its neighbors greater than a threshold.

**Debugging:** I debugged my code to determine where the infinite loop was happening and found out that it was in the `if-else` code block under the `while` loop in the `main` function.

1. I checked my code only for the first column and it worked. But, when I generalized my code, it runs into an infinite loop.
2. Tried to reduce the requirement of the neighborhood pattern; if only a few neighbors were greater than the threshold, then that point would be sufficient for a "final contour"
3. I checked to see if all rows were being iterated through, and saw that the row count kept resetting.
4. To solve point 3, I set a count to cut-off the infinite loop if it exceeds 200. But, the output "final contour" image is the same as the initial mask image.

I have run out of ideas on how to remove my error. Again, help would be appreciated very much!

This is my code:

```
// function to get the neigbourhood pattern 

bool checkLBP(unsigned char *GMOtemp, unsigned char *contour, int &row, int &col, int width, int thresh)
{ 
const int arrSize = 9; 
const int semiArrSize = 6; 


// for first column, need only 6 neighbours 
// since it is at one end of the image

if( col == 0 ) {

    int array [semiArrSize]; 

    // start storing values in the array
    array[0] = GMOtemp[(row*width) + (col)];
    array[1] = GMOtemp[((row+1)*width) + (col)];
    array[2] = GMOtemp[((row+2)*width) + (col)];
    array[3] = GMOtemp[(row*width) + (col+1)];
    array[4] = GMOtemp[((row+1)*width) + (col+1)];
    array[5] = GMOtemp[((row+2)*width) + (col+1)];

    int cnt = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<semiArrSize; i++) {
        if(array[i] >= thresh) {
        cnt++; 
        }
    }
    printf("\n cnt %d \n",cnt);
    if( cnt >= 2 ) { 
        return true; 
    }
    else { 
        return false; 
    }
}   

// for last column, need only 6 neighbours

else if( col == width - 1) {

    int array [semiArrSize]; 

    // start storing values in the array
    array[0] = GMOtemp[(row*width) + (col)];
    array[1] = GMOtemp[((row+1)*width) + (col)];
    array[2] = GMOtemp[((row+2)*width) + (col)];
    array[3] = GMOtemp[(row*width) + (col-1)];
    array[4] = GMOtemp[((row+1)*width) + (col-1)];
    array[5] = GMOtemp[((row+2)*width) + (col-1)];

    int cnt = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<semiArrSize; i++) {
        if(array[i] >= thresh) {
        cnt++; 
        }
    }
    printf("\n cnt %d \n",cnt);
    if( cnt >= 2 ) { 
        return true; 
    }
    else { 
        return false; 
    }
}   
else {

    int array [arrSize]; 

    // start filling all the elements 
    array[0] = GMOtemp[((row)*width) +(col-1)];
    array[1] = GMOtemp[((row)*width) +(col)];
    array[2] = GMOtemp[((row)*width) +(col+1)];
    array[3] = GMOtemp[((row+1)*width) +(col-1)];
    array[4] = GMOtemp[((row+1)*width) +(col)];
    array[5] = GMOtemp[((row+1)*width) +(col+1)];
    array[6] = GMOtemp[((row+2)*width) +(col-1)];
    array[7] = GMOtemp[((row+2)*width) +(col)];
    array[8] = GMOtemp[((row+2)*width) +(col+1)];

    int cnt = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<arrSize; i++) {
        if(array[i] >= thresh) {
        cnt++; 
        }
    }
    printf("\n cnt %d \n",cnt);
    if( cnt >= 1) { 
        return true; 
    }
    else { 
        return false; 
    }
}

}
```

**main()**

```
// ... previous code to do blurring of the image. 


// code to get the point-coordinates from the "initial mask" image 
std::vector<int> setC;
std::vector<int> setR;  

for(int xc = 0; xc < input.cols; xc++) {
for(int xr = 0; xr < input.rows; xr++) {

    int val = mask[xr*input.cols + xc];

    if(val == 255) {
        //setC[i] = xc; 
        //setR[i] = xr; 
        //i++; 
        setC.push_back(xc);
        setR.push_back(xr);
        }
    }
}


// get the LBP pattern
// LBP PATTERN IS A 3X3 NEIGHBOURHOOD
std::vector<int>::iterator mc1 = setC.begin();
std::vector<int>::iterator mr1 = setR.begin();

int rr = 0;
int cc = 0; 

int width = input.cols; 
//rowcount = 0;
int infiniteCount = 0;

unsigned char *GMOtemp; 
unsigned char *contour;

GMOtemp = (unsigned char*) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * input.rows * input.cols);
contour = (unsigned char*) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * input.rows * input.cols);

memcpy(GMOtemp, OCVout2.data, sizeof(unsigned char) * input.rows * input.cols); 
memset(contour, 0, sizeof(unsigned char) * input.rows * input.cols);

while( (mc1 != setC.end()) && (mr1 != setR.end()) ) {


    //looping:

    rr = *mr1; // get row and col
    cc = *mc1; 
    printf("\n %d %d \n", rr, cc); 


    rr++; // increment the row
    bool result = checkLBP(GMOtemp, contour, rr, cc, width, sum);
    //printf("\n %d \n", rr);


    if(result == true)
    {
        contour[rr*width + cc] = 255; // set current point to be equal to 255
        mc1++; // increment the vector iterators - so, go to next column
        mr1++;

    }

    else { 
        do{         

            rr++; 
            result = checkLBP(GMOtemp, contour, rr, cc, width, sum);
            infiniteCount++;
            //printf("\n rr %d \n", rr);
            //printf("\n %d \n", infiniteCount);
            if (rr == (input.rows - 1) || infiniteCount == 200) {
                contour[rr*width + cc] = 255;
                mr1++;
                mc1++;
                infiniteCount = 0;
                result = true; 
                break;
            }
            //printf("\n rr %d \n", rr);
        } while(result == false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my infinite loop by forcing the `if..else` code block to iterate from the current row to the last row in a `for` loop. This is the code:

```
while( mm < ind ) {

    // 'ind' corresponds to number of coordinate-sets = 254
    // I used two arrays here, each was set to 256 (width of image).

    int rr = setR[mm]; // get row and col
    int cc = setC[mm]; 
    //printf("\n %d %d \n", rr, cc); 

    rr = rr + skiprows; // increment row; to skip if needed (skiprows = 0 now) 
    bool result = checkLBP(GMOtemp, rr, cc, width, height, sum);
    //printf("\n %d \n", rr);


    if(result == true)
    {
        if(rr<height){
        contour[rr*width + cc] = 255; // set current point to be equal to 255
        mm++;

        }
    }

    else {

        int check = 0; // boolean check variable - to see if none of the neighbors of a given pixel are greater
        rr = rr + skiprows; // increment row 
        for(int currRow = rr; currRow < height; currRow = currRow+skiprows)
        {
            result = checkLBP(GMOtemp, currRow, cc, width, height, sum);

            if( result == true) 
            {
                contour[currRow*width + cc] = 255;
                mm++;
                check = 1;
                break; // break out of for-loop

            }
        }
        if(check == 0)
        { 
            mm++;
        }

    }       

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to break out of the `while( (mc1 != setC.end()) && (mr1 != setR.end()) ) {}` loop, am I right? If so, you have placed your `break` in the wrong place.

The `break` will only break out of your `do{...}while(result==false)` loop and not your big while loop. A hint would be to use a FLAG. Do let me know if problem persists. Peace.

Comment: I solved it last night. In the `if( result == false)` loop, I converted the while loop into a for loop. So, what I did was I forced the iteration from the current row to the end, checked the result and hit `break` only when `result == true`. I also included a `check` variable to see if all the results were false. If check was set to true (the flag you suggested), I would go to the next coordinate-set. I'll post the code later today as I am away from the actual system I wrote the code on.

Comment: No, I want to just break out of my `if.. else` loop. Remember, in the `else` part of the loop, if all the pixel neighbors for all the pixels in the current column (iterated over one by one) were lesser than the threshold, that means that there is no pixel that can be set to 255 in the current column. So, I have to move on to the next column, get the next coordinate set, and do the same operation.

Comment: @eagle, glad you solved it then, yup, your `check` and my `flag` is actually the same thing and is the step taken for such checking. Also, if you are trying to break out of the `if...else` loop, `break` will not do it. `break` doesn't work on `if...else`, usually people use `goto` instead, but I am not a fan of that. Still, glad you solved it and I hope I helped out in same way. Cheers(: